# How to change mat-button font color

Tags: html, angular, angular-material

I have a mat-button with the following code:

```html
<button mat-button (click)="getStock()" >Go </button>
```

I have a background color for the whole app in styles.css

```css
html { background-color:#a9c5f2 };
```

The css component code that corresponds with the mat-button

```css
.mat-button {
    display: inline-block;
    font-weight: 400;
    text-align: center;
    white-space: nowrap;
    vertical-align: middle;
    -webkit-user-select: none;
    -moz-user-select: none;
    -ms-user-select: none;
    user-select: none;
    border: 1px solid transparent;
    padding: .375rem .75rem;
    font-size: 1rem;
    line-height: 1.5;
    border-radius: .25rem;
    transition: color .15s ease-in-out,background-color .15s ease-in-out,border-color .15s ease-in-out,box-shadow .15s ease-in-out;
    background-color: #659bf2;
    border-color: #659bf2;
    height:100px;
    width:300px;
    white-space: normal;
    color: black !important;
}
```

The text in the mat-button in the browser is gray.

How may I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a directive built over this that will take a colour option.

```
<button mat-button color="black" (click)="getStock()">Go</button>
```

Also found this [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-material-button) that shows some examples of what you can do with `mat-button`

[Official Documentation](https://material.angular.io/components/button/api).

Comment: I tried the 'color = "black"' and the color is still gray. Let me try removing the color background.

Comment: Let me know how you get on, try and copy an example from the link :-)

Comment: I guess u've missed the **style** keyword. Try using `<button mat-button (click)="getStock()" style="color:black">Go </button>`.
BTW @Reggie1983 your code works perfectly fine for me i.e., I get the text in black color only.